# Hide New Sheet tab

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, excel-2007

How can I get rid of the last workbook tab that allows a user to add a new sheet in my Excel Viewer control?

[image: SO16766034 question example]

I have found the following code to hide the button in the above image:

```
ExcelViewer1.Application.CommandBars["Workbook tabs"]._  
              Controls["Sheet List"].Visible = false;
```

but it throws a COM Exception:

> "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a com component".

The same command works for other commandbars like Ply, Cell.

Comment: You could protect the workbook structure. Then the button will not do anything.

Comment: I know this teylyn, but i am looking for a way to hide it completely because my boss focused just on this.

Comment: Hi @pnuts. No, I need to show sheet tabs to user!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub remove()
  ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
End Sub

Sub add()
  ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to hide the tab bar (at bottom) of excel through C#...

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application appExcel = new 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
appExcel.Visible = false;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
workbook.SaveAs(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\a.xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

> appExcel.ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = false;

```
appExcel.Workbooks.Close();
appExcel.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
```