# Hide tabs programmatically in Excel, EPPlus, C#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I would like to hide all the tabs in an excel workbook. I can set a sheet to hidden, but this is not a great solution because I still would like to be able to link that the sheet, which is not possible when I hide the entire sheet.

So, what I'm asking is this: Is there a way to just hide the tabs at the bottom of the workbook, but keep the sheets visible and linkable?

Comment: Can this be done in excel normally?  I have never seen that as an option without using VBA.  If that is the case you can add VBA code to the EPPus output assuming running an xlsm is not restricted in the destination environent.

Answer (score 2):

Found it.

ExcelWorkbook.View.ShowSheetTabs = false;

Answer (score 0):

You can find full sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47311246/1690709)

```
appExcel.ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious to know if using VBA below would still allow you to link? I have used below VBA to hide a particular tab (sheet 2 in this example) upon opening the workbook (every time). I'll have to give it a shot and see if I can link to that tab from a different workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
      Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVisible
      Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End Sub
```